# How to get all columns from the child table and parent table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I currently have a several tables of different types of items. Each table has different columns, and they all inherit the primary `items` table. Here is a brief example:

```
CREATE TABLE items 
(
    id serial,
    name character varying,
    description character varying
)

CREATE TABLE weapons
(
    damage smallint,
    accuracy smallint
) INHERITS (items)
```

I am trying to allow users to search for an item by name, and get all of the information regarding that item, not only the columns from the `items` table. Since I do not know which child table the item will be in, I cannot do:

```
SELECT * FROM ONLY parent NATURAL FULL JOIN child;
```

Is there any way to get all the columns of all child tables without knowning what the child table is? And if not, what would be the best way to make this feature work?

### Solution

Use the following to get the origin tabe, which will then be used to query all the information from that table:

```
SELECT id, tableoid::regclass AS origin FROM items WHERE name = $1;
```

Comment: `select *, tableoid::regclass as origin from items;` gives you the origin table for each row.

Comment: @Abelisto Very helpful, thank you!

Comment: The convention on this site is to keep the question and answer separate, so rather than editing the solution into the question, you're encouraged to add an answer below your own question if none of the existing answers matches.

Answer (score 0):

The query planner needs to know what tables are going to be read, and what columns included in the final result, so I don't think there will be any single query that can say "include column X if Y, but column Z if not".

The best that I can think of is to `LEFT JOIN` all the child tables, so your result set contains all the possible columns, but most of them will be `NULL`.